# vim mksession issue

Tags: vim

I use [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2010) plugin to manage my sessions. I can sees that it writes file to save session. The file looks ok and session is loading ok. But It does not correctly save my color scheme. After session opening the color sheme is another. What it can be? Why I cannot restore my session?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is just a wrapper for Vim's built-in `mksession` command. You should check your `sessionsoptions` and make sure it contains `globals`. What is your color scheme anyway?

Comment: I add the line "set sessionoptions=blank,buffers,curdir,folds,globals,help,localoptions,options,tabpages,winsize" to my vimrc, it does not work.